# How to delete items from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, oop, collections, properties

I have a collection ObservableCollection called Datasets. I have a method for delete items from Datasets but not working. Can anyone help me?
My property is not good, what to put in set?

```
    private void ExecuteRemoveDatasetCommand(DefaultDataset dataset)
    {
        Datasets.Remove(dataset);
    }   
public ObservableCollection<DefaultDataset> DefaultDatasets
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<DefaultDataset> defaultDataSet = new ObservableCollection<DefaultDataset>();
            foreach (var data in TemplateSystems.Select(data => data.DefaultDataSets).FirstOrDefault())
            {
                defaultDataSet.Add(data);
            }
            return defaultDataSet;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? From what I see there, you are removing the dataset from another collection, not "DefaultDatasets"? Why are you doing the FirstOrDefault while looping the queryable?

It's a bit difficult to understand, maybe if you comment what are you trying to do or put a bit more code...

Comment: I don't understand why you have a setter at all. Why did you write a setter?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is  your **DefaultDataset** is not implemented the [IEquatable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) so the system not able to find your element is the list.